# migrating from ie8 to ie9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, css, internet-explorer-9

What changes should be made in an application while migrating from ie8 to ie9 regarding css,html, javascript,DOM

Comment: If you always adhered to standards, you won't have to face many problems.

Answer (score 3):

Compliance with W3C standards. That's all.

Internet Explorer 9 is Microsoft's way to full Web Standards' support.

In most of the cases, you'd remove previous versions' CSS, DOM hacks. Or conditionally allow them for versions lower than 9.0, in order to render your pages in standards mode.

Now you can take advantage of some CSS 3.0 and HTML5 features, but keep in mind that most of them are working draft, yet to be approved by W3C and browser support in other navigators can differ their expected behavior.

Check this MSDN index if you want to learn more:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740469

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft have produced a tool that you can add to your pages which will inform you about changes that may effect your web site.

Just add the following javascript code into your head tag before any othe scripts, then opperate the site as normal, it will then produce a report detailing things you should fix.

```
<script src="http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/CompatInspector/inspector.js"></script>
```

To learn more about the tool  goto:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/27/ie9-compat-inspector.aspx