# migrating from ie8 to ie9

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [migrating from ie8 to ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855901/migrating-from-ie8-to-ie9)

Is their any guidelines on migrating from ie8 to ie9 to run an application? What are the points to be considered for css, html, javascript before migrating?

Comment: IE9 have support for HTML5 and CSS3, unlike IE8.

Comment: IE8 has support for HTML5 and CSS3. Just less of them then IE9 has (and IE9 is a very long way from 100% support).

Comment: -1 for asking a duplicate question even though the original had good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705